# How to find minimum value of $ \sqrt {2x^2+2x+1} +\sqrt{2x^2-10x+13} $?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

The solution to this question was confusing for me:

$ \sqrt {2x^2+2x+1} +\sqrt{2x^2-10x+13}$

$\sqrt{x^2+(x+1)^2}+\sqrt{(x-3)^2+(x-2)^2}$

$\sqrt{(y-0)^2+(x+1)^2}+\sqrt{(y-3)^2+(x-2)^2}$ (y=x, say)

(-1,0) and (2,3)

The shortest path between these points which touches y=x is $\sqrt{20}$, which is the answer to the question.

Why did this method work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can think of $\sqrt{x^2 + (x+1)^2}$ as the distance from $(0,-1)$ to $(x,x)$. We can think of $\sqrt{(x-3)^2 + (x-2)^2}$ as the distance from $(x,x)$ to $(2,3)$.

(We could have chosen either $(0,-1)$ or $(-1,0)$ for the first point, and either $(2,3)$ or $(3,2)$ for the second point, but this choice is one of the convenient ones.)

So the question is: what is the minimum length of a path from $(0,-1)$ to $(x,x)$ (an arbitrary point on the line $y=x$) and then to $(2,3)$?

Well, any path from $(0,-1)$ to $(2,3)$ crosses the line $y=x$, since $(0,-1)$ is below the line and $(2,3)$ is above the line. So it's just enough to find the shortest path from $(0,-1)$ to $(2,3)$, and that shortest path is a straight line, of length $\sqrt{(2-0)^2 + (3-(-1))^2} = \sqrt{20}$.

The straight line from $(0,-1)$ to $(2,3)$ crosses the line $y=x$ at $(1,1)$, so $x=1$ is the value of $x$ that achieves this minimum.

Answer (score 1):

To minimize $\sqrt {2x^2+2x+1} +\sqrt{2x^2-10x+13}$ is equivalent to solve for $x,y,r$

$$
\cases{
(y-0)^2+(x+1)^2=r^2\\
(y-3)^2+(x-2)^2=r^2\\
x = y
}
$$

thus we obtain:

$$
(x,y,r) = (1,1,\sqrt{5})
$$

giving

$$
\min_x(\sqrt {2x^2+2x+1} +\sqrt{2x^2-10x+13})=2\sqrt{5}
$$

[image]